# How to send a sms in Android without it going into the sent box?

Tags: java, android, sms

I am currently using

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

to send sms messages from an android phone. However it always goes immediately into the phone's sent box (`"content://sms/sent"`) is there away to send sms messsages without it going into the sent box?

**P.S.** I know how to delete messages from the sent box but that requires waiting for about a second before it is stored in the box.

Comment: Hey, have u tried to use ACTION_SENDTO to send SMS instead of SMSMa nager?

Comment: I believe this opens up the user's default sms app which is not what I want...